# How to call a method of a class which has dependency injection in Loopback 4 (typescript)?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, loopback4

```
export class CronController {
    constructor(
        @service() public syncService: SyncService,
    ) { }

    async cron() {
        this.syncService.pitSyncCompanies();
    }
}   

@injectable({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
      export class SyncService {
        constructor(
            @repository(CompanyRepository) public companyRepository: CompanyRepository,
        ) { }
    
        async pitSyncCompanies() {
            console.log('Hi');
        }
    }
```

How do I instantiate CronController so as to call method cron()?
I can't just create object = new CronController() as its constructor accepts arguments and I am not sure what to pass here.
How to call a method of a class which has dependency injection in Loopback 4 (typescript)?

Comment: `this. syncService.pitSyncCompanies()`. Not sure how dependency injection is related to the question..

Comment: I have modified the question. Here, how do I create an object of CronController? Because its constructor needs @service() public syncService: SyncService

Comment: You shouldn't call `new`, you need to get it from dependency injection container/ context or whatever it is called in this framework. Look at docs

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the framework would kick-start the "initial resolution" of a binding (e.g, In a HTTP request, the framework would resolve the appropriate REST Controller, which would then kick-start the resolution tree for the necessary dependencies).

If you want "kick-start" the resolution yourself (i.e. without any triggers from the framework itself), you're probably looking for [createProxyWithInterceptors()](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.context.createproxywithinterceptors.html). This is useful for the rare circumstance when the code you're writing is outside of the Context.

For example:

```js
// This does not bind `CronController` to Context.
// It also assumes that the Context has the necessary...
// bindings already added to it (i.e. `SyncService`).

// If the app already depends on `@loopback/core`, import...
// from that package instead for consistency. `@loopback/core`...
// re-exports `@loopback/context`.

import {createProxyWithInterceptors} from '@loopback/context';

createProxyWithInterceptors(CronController, myContextHere);
```

It should be noted that the return value of this function is an [AsyncProxy](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.context.asyncproxy.html), which is not strictly type-compatible with the original class.

It is important that this is not necessary for most use-cases and is mostly meant for custom [Server](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.core.server.html) implementations.

In a typical REST project using `@loopback/rest`'s built-in Server implementation, you would resolve `CronController` in a REST Controller like this:

```js
// This example uses Constructor Injection, but Property- and Parameter Injection are supported as well.
// This example also assumes that `CronController` was bound using `this.add(createBindingFromClass(CronController))` in the Application/Context constructor
export class MyRESTController {
  constructor(
    @inject(CronController)
    cronController: CronController
  ) { }
}
```